# Representations of the Poincare Group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

I am concerned about generators of the Poincare Lie Group that is responsible for boosts and rotations (often labelled by $J_{\nu \mu}$).

$J_{\nu \mu}$ is often divided into a term responsible for the spin angular momentum ($S_{\nu \mu}$) and another term responsible for the orbital angular momentum ($L_{\nu \mu}$).  Therefore,

$J_{\nu \mu}$ = $L_{\nu \mu}$ + $S_{\nu \mu}$

I am wondering why is the $S_{0 \mu}$ components equal to zero?

Comment: This depends on a particular choice of coordinate that you are using (time is the $0$th coordinate). Then it all boils down to the fact that $O(1,3)$ contains the orthogonal subgroup $O(3)$ fixing the $0$th coordinate vector pointwise, hence, the 1st column vector of the corresponding group elements is $(1,0,....))$. On the level of the Lie algebra, this becomes $(0,...,0)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you elaborate a bit?  You said that "This depends" so do you mean the _(0) components need not be zero?

Comment: Yes, for instance, if you, say, swap the 1st and 4th coordinates making the Lorentzian form $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 -x_4^2$.